# Making axis of plot resizable using Viewbox

Tags: javascript, d3.js, resize, axis

I am trying to make myself familiar with resizable d3 plots. However I am having trouble with the x- and y axis of my plot.

The x-axis is displayed against a white background (instead of blue) after window size is below a certain threshold. Additionally, the y-axis highest value is cut of, since I am not able to shorten the axis. Furthermore, the y-axis totally disappears when window size is too small.

I have also tried to put both axes inside the rect (marked by a comment), but then they aren't displayed at all.

As you can see, I am using bootstrap to make up the styling in the HTML. Regarding the resizing I am looking for a JavaScript only solution with Viewbox, as already indicated in the code.

In short, the box seems to be resizable while the axes don't.

What am I missing? Help is very much appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-info">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <h5>some title</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <div id="plot"></div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="row mt-3"></div>

<script src="./js/d3.js"></script>

<script>

    var height = 500;
    var width = 500;
    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 0 };
    

    var svg = d3.select("#plot")
        .append("div")
        .classed("svg-container", true)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
        .classed("svg-content-responsive", true);

    svg.append("rect")//tried to insert axis insight this rect, however they disappeard
        .classed("rect", true)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("fill", "white");

    var xAchsis = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 85000000])
        .range([0, width]);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(80," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xAchsis));

    svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "x label")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("x", 300)
        .attr("y", 550)
        .text("x-label");

    var yAchsis = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 400000])
        .range([height, 0]);

        svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yAchsis))
        .attr("transform", "translate(80 ,0)");

        svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y label")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("y", -10)
        .attr("x", 250)
        .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
        .text("y-label");
</script>
```